# How do I wipe my phone after incorrect PIN (device wipe threshold), or is this not supported?

Tags: email, security

I would like my device to be wiped if I enter my PIN wrong 10 times, similar to the iPhone. However, this doesn't seem to be a feature I can find.

I wouldn't normally mind, but our mail admins recently put a security policy in place that requires `DeviceWipeThreshold` be enabled for mobile devices to synchronize with the mail server. The error I'm getting is:

> mail.contoso.com requires that certain security policies be enforced before you can sync your inforamtion. Contact a support person or your service provider.
>
> Last tried 9 minutes ago
>
> Error code: 85010013

Is this feature not supported on Windows Phone 7? (I'm using Mango, but it is a first generation device)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your mail system is Microsoft Exchange Server (and they have it configured properly) it will work. Right now my phone is wiped after 3 incorrect entries. There isn't a way for you to change that threshold, but I assume your mail admin can.

How did you come to the conclusion that this is what the problem is? The error you have been given just means something is enabled in the Exchange Server that your phone can not support ([reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2464593)).

> An Exchange ActiveSync mailbox policy has been implemented with
>   parameters the WP7 device cannot completely enforce.
>
> WP7 supports the following policy parameters:
>
> - PasswordRequired
> - MinPasswordLength
> - IdleTimeoutFrequencyValue
> - DeviceWipeThreshold
> - AllowSimplePassword
> - PasswordExpiration
> - PasswordHistory
> - DisableRemovableStorage
> - DisableIrDA
> - DisableDesktopSync
> - BlockRemoteDesktop
> - BlockInternetSharing
>
> ---
>
> There are three methods to resolve issue.
>
> **Method 1**   Modify the existing Exchange ActiveSync policy to apply only WP7 supported policy parameters.
>
> **Method 2**   Create a new Exchange ActiveSync policy that applies the supported policy parameters WP7 devices can implement, and assign
>   this policy to WP7 users.
>
> **Method 3**   Enable the parameter to Allow Non-provisionable Devices in your Exchange ActiveSync policy.

Comment: Thanks for this! After a lot of back and forth with our admins, it turns out that it wasn't the `DeviceWipeThreshold` causing the error, but instead a mail encryption setting with according to our admins Windows Phone 7 does not support. They disabled the setting and my device was able to connect.